# Username Modification while Retaining Data Structure

Tags: users

I've tried this in the past with zero success.  How do I change  the `/home/USER` directory for a user, when I change their username, and how do I update their username without causing massive breakage?

Comment: Your question is not clear - "retaining Data structure" would imply to not rename anything, but in the text you state it differently - please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If you change only the username (presumably by editing `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, and `/etc/group`), then simply doing `mv /home/USER /home/NEWUSER` as root should be enough, assuming you also changed the directory in `/etc/passwd` which is used as the home for that user.

If the UID (and or GID) was also changed, you'll need to run `chmod -R NEWUSER.NEWGROUP /home/NEWUSER` as well.

Comment: I've never gotten username changes to work properly... so basically what you're saying is i edit `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, and `/etc/group` to do the username changes... and then move the home directory as root?  Wouldn't i have to `usermod` so that the home directory is recognized in the new path?

Comment: How were you doing the username change? You can use `usermod` to change the home directory path, instead, but if you're already editing `/etc/passwd` to change the username, it's faster to just edit it there.

Comment: dobey, the point of this question in a nutshell was to figure out the correct method of changing the user while retaining data structure.  I might've missed a step or two when I tried a while ago, but I'll take another stab with a test user (so as to make sure I don't break my ACTUAL user)